# How to use AND criteria in the SUMIF excel

Tags: excel, sum

How to use AND criteria in the `SUMIF`, I used `=COUNTIF(I3:I12,AND(">2","<4"))` it shows the wrong result, and `=COUNTIF(I3:I12,{">2","<4"})` is `OR` criteria, I don't want to use `COUNTIFS` for multi-array, then how to simply use the `AND` criteria?

Comment: What's the problem with COUNTIFS? See also https://exceljet.net/formula/count-cells-between-two-numbers

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to COUNTIFS, you could use COUNTIF to get all the numbers greater than two and remove numbers greater than four to get the range:

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A12,">2") - COUNTIF(A2:A12, ">=4")
```

Comment: so, there is no direct way to write in one  `AND` criteria?

Comment: @A.Oreo based on my knowledge and quick search, I couldn't find any way of doing it by directly using AND. I could be wrong. Note that using COUNTIF as I did is considered the 'legacy' way to do it, where as using COUNTIFS was introduced in newer versions of excel.

Answer (score 0):

Use `=Countifs()` function.

```
=COUNTIFS(I3:I12,">" & 2,I3:I12,"<" & 5)
```